# How to break 'foreach' in php when reach a specific tag name?

Tags: php, xml, foreach, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to import a .xml table file to mysql using php, it worked fine, but i want to upgrade my code so i can recognize more variations of xml tables.
So basically the problem is, i got this code ( just a example, my real table is bigger) of .xml file that I'm trying to read:

```
...
<Table ss:StyleID="s62">
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s75"><Data ss:Type="String">Mercado</Data></Cell>
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s75"><Data ss:Type="String">Segmento</Data></Cell>
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Codigo do Projeto</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"><Data ss:Type="String">Mineração</Data></Cell>
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"><Data ss:Type="String">Portuário</Data></Cell>
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"/>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"><Data ss:Type="String">Portuário</Data></Cell>
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"/>
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"><Data ss:Type="String">Greenfield</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"/>
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"><Data ss:Type="String">Greenfield</Data></Cell>
     <Cell ss:StyleID="s90"><Data ss:Type="String">Large CapEx&gt;&gt;maior que 500MBRL</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
</Table>

<Worksheet ss:Name="cod">

  <Table ss:StyleID="s62">
... ...
  </Table>

...
```

Well, what i want to do is to get the row and data element using getElementByTagName, but i just want to get whats inside the first Table element, not the second, third and so on...

This is what I've tried:

```
    $tabelas = $arquivo->getElementsByTagName("Table");
    $rows = $arquivo->getElementsByTagName("Row");

    $contRow = 1; (This is just to create a condition to jump the first row)
    $contTabelas = TRUE;
    foreach ($tabelas as $tabela) {
        if ($contTabelas) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                if ($contRow > 1) {
                    $Mercado = $row->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $Segmento = $row->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(1)->nodeValue;
                    $CodigoDoProjeto = $row->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(2)->nodeValue;

                }
                $contRow++;
            }
            $contTabelas = FALSE;
        }
    }
```

It seems that the "foreach($rows as $row)" is getting all the rows from the xml file, but i just want whats inside the "Table" tag. How can I do that??

P.S: I got another problem to solve later, there are a lot of row without an item (Data tag) inside, so i cant get those and the program just jumps to the next one, but i think the solution is just get the 'cell' tag instead 'data'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access just the first table in the tables array by doing $tablas[0]. Now you don't even need a foreach loop.

```
<?php

$tabelas = $arquivo->getElementsByTagName("Table");

$tablea = $tabelas[0];

$rows = $tablea->getElementsByTagName("Row");

$contRow = 1;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($contRow > 1) {
        $Mercado = $row->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $Segmento = $row->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(1)->nodeValue;
        $CodigoDoProjeto = $row->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(2)->nodeValue;

    }
    $contRow++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an OpenXML spreadsheet if that is the case you should look for the namespace definitions. I expect you to find `xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"` and `xmlns::ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"`.

This is the same namespace actually, but XML attributes do not have a default namespace, so they need an prefix/alias.

With that you can use Xpath expressions to fetch specific data from the document:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('spreadsheet', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet');

$records = [];
$rows = $xpath->evaluate('((//spreadsheet:Table)[1]/spreadsheet:Row)[position() > 1]');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $records[] = [
      'Mercado' => $xpath->evaluate('string(spreadsheet:Cell[1])', $row),
      'Segmento' => $xpath->evaluate('string(spreadsheet:Cell[2])', $row),
      'CodigoDoProjeto' => $xpath->evaluate('string(spreadsheet:Cell[3])', $row)
    ];
}


var_dump($records);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Mercado"]=>
    string(11) "Mineração"
    ["Segmento"]=>
    string(10) "Portuário"
    ["CodigoDoProjeto"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Mercado"]=>
    string(10) "Portuário"
    ["Segmento"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["CodigoDoProjeto"]=>
    string(10) "Greenfield"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Mercado"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Segmento"]=>
    string(10) "Greenfield"
    ["CodigoDoProjeto"]=>
    string(30) "Large CapEx>>maior que 500MBRL"
  }
}
```

`//spreadsheet:Table` fetch any `Table`, `(//spreadsheet:Table)[1]` limits this to the first, `(//spreadsheet:Table)[1]/spreadsheet:Row` returns the `Row` elements of the first `Table`.

`spreadsheet:Cell[1]` returns the first `Cell` and `string(spreadsheet:Cell[1])` returns the text content of it. If it did not match a node, it will return an empty string.